# Just want to ask an mathematical induction question which I've tried to solve.. but still cannot get the LHS and RHS.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I have tried to solve this question, but it's kinda tricky here when I form a LHS equation by myself it doesn't equals to the RHS. 
Can anyone here provide me a step by step guide to proof it?

[image: problem]

Suppose that $n$ a's and $n$ b's are distributed around the outside of a circle.Use mathematical induction to prove that for all integers $n \geq 1$, given any such arrangement it is possible to find a starting point so that if one travels around the circle in a clockwise direction, the number of a's one has passed is never less than the number of b's one has passed.

Comment: They dont allow me to add picture.. if you guys can help please click on the link above

Comment: Your problem doesn't involve an equation anywhere, and neither should the solution. What do you mean by RHS and LHS?

Comment: i mean Right hand side(RHS) and Left hand side(LHS)
It should be a equation which is 1+2+3+4+...n=n(n+1)
On the left side of the equal sign is LHS whereas right side is RHS.

Comment: No, it should not be such an equation. There shouldn't be any equations when you solve this problem. See the answer below, for instance. It is a full answer and has no equations.

Comment: Hmm.. it's a bit different from what I learnt from my lecture notes. Why it doesn't have the equal sign?

Comment: I've made an edit to add the text of the problem so that people won't need to click through the link.  I don't have enough reputation to make the edit unilaterally, but if you'll accept it I believe it will go through and everyone will be able to see the text.

Answer (score 0):

The proposition is obviously true when $n=1$ because you can start at $a$.

Now assume it's true for all circles with $2n$ labels equally apportioned among $a$ and $b$.  Consider a circle with $2n+2$ equally apportioned labels.

There will necessarily be a place on the circle where an $a$ and a $b$ are immediately adjacent with $b$ clockwise from $a$.  Remove those two adjacent vertices and you have remaining a circle with $2n$ equally apportioned labels.  By your inductive hypothesis, you can find a starting place where you have passed at least as many $a$s as $b$s.  When you reinsert the two vertices you have removed, you will pass the removed $a$ before you pass the removed $b$, so the property you need still holds and you are done.

**Edit:**

There's a second way to look at most proofs by induction that you may find helpful.  You can think of them as considering the least $n$ where your proposition fails, and then proving that the proposition does not in fact fail there.   Let's look at how this methodology plays out for your problem.

Suppose the proposition is false for some $n$.  Since any non-empty set of natural numbers has a least element, let's choose the smallest possible $n$ for which the proposition fails, and consider a circle with $n$ $a$ labels and $n~b$ labels.  As above, we know there must be a place on the circle where an $a$ and a $b$ are immediately adjacent with $a$ clockwise from $b$ so let's erase those two vertices.  There are two possibilities.

**Case 1:**  There are no vertices left after you erase those two vertices.  In that case, the two vertices you erased were the only two vertices around the circle, you can start your path at the $a$ vertex, and in fact the proposition did not fail, contrary to your assumption.  That contradiction proves the result for Case $1$.

**Case 2:**  There *are* vertices remaining after you erase two vertices as above.  Then the circle with two vertices erased has fewer than $2n$ vertices so it's smaller than the smallest case for which the proposition fails.  Therefore, there must be a path around this smaller number of vertices that works.  Start there, and we will always have reached at least as many $a$ vertices as $b$ vertices until we reach the two vertices that we erased.  We will add an $a$ vertex before we add a $b$ vertex, so the path continues to work when we traverse the two erased vertices, and in fact the net difference when we have passed them both will be the same as it was in the path on the smaller set of vertices.  Thus, when we complete the circle, the path will continue to work (because it worked in the smaller circle) and again, contrary to our assumption, the proposition does not in fact fail here, contradicting the assumption we used to reach Case $2$.  This completes the proof.

Comment: Why do we say that n=1 is true? is it because there are 6 a and 6 b in the circle?
sorry for asking stupid question. i am new to mathematical induction

Comment: The case $n=1$ means that the circle only has $1~a$ and $1~b$.  The idea of induction is that you start with the small case and then use it as a building block to prove the next step.  So first you show the statement is true for $1~a$ and $1~b$, and then you use that knowledge to prove the statement is true for $2$ of each letter, and so on.

Comment: That means 2n+2...+n = 2n ? 
Then i can prove using the equation?

Comment: Oh, dear.  I'm afraid you may have a fundamental misunderstanding of how induction works.  How would you state the problem for the case $n=1$?

Comment: I got to use 2 methods to do it from what I've learnt.
1) Basis step.
Which is to prove both side are equal when n=1
2)Inductive Step
Which we change n to k, and then we do P(k+1). (Substitution)
And we expand the Left Hand Side equation to see if it is tally with the Right Hand Side.
Thank you for your patience. If this method correct?

Comment: Not quite.  The method of induction isn't limited to equations, and this is a case where there aren't any equations in sight.  You're trying to prove some statement (*not necessarily an equation*) is true for all $n$.  You start by proving that statement is true in the base case.  So let's take things by baby steps here.  What is the theorem that you're trying to prove is true for all $n$?

Comment: Do we form a universal statement? 
Sorry I was looking on my lecture notes

Comment: Forget about your notes for the moment.  Focus on understanding the concept.  Stated in terms of $n$, what is the statement that you're trying to prove in this specific problem?

Comment: Okay, with this question. I will need to proof that n a's passed by one person is equal to n b's on a clock wise direction right?

Comment: Not quite.  You need to prove that something is always possible.  Take another shot at stating the problem in terms of $n$.  You need to prove that *what* is always possible for any $n$?

It's getting late here so maybe someone else will pick up the effort.  Or perhaps you should speak to your professor, because I think you're having a fundamental misunderstanding of how induction works.